# Load data when the text box gets value from popup window

Tags: javascript, jsp, events, dom-events

I have a text field. And a search button followed by the text box. When click on the search button, a new popup window will be opened. From the window I will select an id out of the populated ids. On select the radio button the popup will close and the text box in the parent window holds the selected id., using

```
 opener.document.profile.inp_type.value = val2;
 window.close();
```

My requirement is,

Upon the popup window closes and the text box gets the value from the popup window, I need to load some values in the select box below to the text box based on the id selected. So how can I do that?

```
<input type="text" value="" id="inp_type" name="inp_type" /> <img src=""  onclick="openPopUp()" />

<select name="sel1" id="sel1" >
<!-- 
When the textbox get the id from popup window, I need to load some data here.
-->
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can submit the `form` in the `opener` window before closing the pop-up window like:

```
opener.document.profile.inp_type.value = val2;
opener.document.formName.submit();
window.close();
```

This will submit the form with the populated field in the parent window and you can populate the drop-down accordingly.